# Thumbnail Control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

Hi all i need to design a control that has a thumbnail views of picture.it can take list of pictures.i need it in wpf.is there any pre existed library of control?
if no how can i design i have no idea
Thanks

was looking something like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/crystal_image_grid_viewer.aspx?msg=3290254

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of pictures you can place a panel (StackPanel, WrapPanel, etc., depends on the behaviour you want) inside a ListBox. Set the panel to be the items host, and set the list of pictures as the ItemsSource.  Something like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="_listBox" >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="true" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

and then in the code behind set _listBox.ItemsSource to your list of pictures.

(or you can have your list of pictures in an ObservableCollection and bind the ListBox to it)

EDIT: as for the thumbnails you can use something like:

```
BitmapImage Picture = new BitmapImage();
Picture.BeginInit();
Picture.UriSource = ... // your picture
Picture.DecodePixelWidth = ... //how big you want your pic
Picture.EndInit();
```

Comment: that is really helping.i need user to be able to click them and when they click them the other control shows it in bigger size.
Secondly ItemsSource requires collection how to make it?

Comment: if you have a List _imageList = new List<Image>(); with your pictures all you need is to set _listBox.ItemsSoure = _imageList;

Comment: as for the other control to show the bigger sized image, you'll need to check the ListBox.SelectedItem ou ListBox.SelectedIndex to find which picture was selected, and display its full size

Answer (score 1):

do you want to show all the images of the list at the same time? I believe you can use the grid and put a picture control in any cell of the grid, you can start with this approach, post your results and ask more specific questions once you have it at least partly done.

Comment: was looking something like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/crystal_image_grid_viewer.aspx?msg=3290254